# Computer shuts down when unplugged

Tags: power-management, shutdown

I have an MSI Wind U100 netbook (they call it a notebook). Every time I unplug the AC adapter the machine shuts down as if the battery is dead. I get a notification that says "battery is critical and is about to shut down" or something to that sense. It did this before but I fixed it by  opening gconf-editor. Then browse to `/apps/gnome-power-manager/general`. and de-select the option `use_time_for_policy`.

But that doesn't work with 11.10. I have also searched and can't find a solution. Anyone?

Comment: maybe your battery is broken?

Comment: Possibly related to http://askubuntu.com/questions/70877/battery-critically-low-at-85

Comment: Battery is not broken, it works under Linux Mint as well as older versions of Ubuntu. I am not that stupid..

Comment: Thanks, that solves my problem too. Ubuntu 11.10 on Lenovo N200

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power 'use-time-for-policy' 'false'
```

Works for various versions of Ubuntu from 11.10 to 17.10 at least.