# Battery Critically Low at 85%?

Tags: 11.10, battery

I, along with many others, have been experiencing a problem with our Ubuntu 11.10 installations on our battery-powered laptop devices: The computer misreads information from the battery, so it thinks the battery will only last a few minutes. I get a critically low message ~85% battery level. Can someone help me?

Here is the link to the whole situation showing all the details and terminal messages on the Ubuntu Forums: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1865832

Answer (score 3, accepted):

People who had same problem I installed Jupiter for them that tend to solve the problem of critical low level of battery in laptops. If you are experiencing such a critical battery level then you can try the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/jupiter
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install jupiter
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

From fix/workaround found in [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11378614&postcount=5).

For 11.04 and older just run:

```
gconftool-2 --type bool --set /apps/gnome-power-manager/general/use_time_for_policy false
```

For 11.10 run:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power 'use-time-for-policy' 'false'
```

This worked for me. It doesn't fix my underlying issue, but it keeps my laptop from continuously suspending.

Comment: For the underlying issue follow this thread [in launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/852406).

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 12.04, Lenovo Ideapad S400. I finally found what worked for me. Take a look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/92794...-battery-value. It says:

Start dconf-editor.
Browse to org->gnome->settings-daemon->plugins->power.
Change the values of percentage-critical and percentage-action to the level you require.
And change use-time-for-policy to false

I just had to install dconf through Ubuntu Software Center to find the way. All the percentages were ok. I turned use-time-for-policy to false and restarted the session. Working fine now. Enjoy... it is always good to remove Windows from a computer.

By the way, before I intended to remove Windows (it is my 77-year-old, mother-in-law computer) after it gets 1060 viruses of 15 different kinds in the first week of use, I called Lenovo in Brazil asking them about warranty. To my surprise, I was told that Windows removal voids warranty... I must return to windows if I need that. You know what? I don't mind. Ubuntu is already installed and, except for this small battery glitch, it seems to recognize all peripherals ok.