# Hibernate dialog apears but doesn't hibernate?

Tags: power-management, battery, hibernate

Followed [this Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/361734/hibernation-is-still-missing-from-menu-in-13-10-after-enabling-via-polkit-how-t) and now whenever I press the button hibernate it just take me to the login screen.

#### For critical battery

I wanted it to hibernate on specific battery % and for that I followed the answer to the [Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92794/how-to-change-critically-low-battery-value) and now what happen is that whenever battery reaches the critical level it just shows a dialog box which says hibernate or cancel honestly I don't need this I want it to just hibernate and if I happen to be there at the critical time and click hibernate, it shows me the login screen like it does when I click the hibernate button ( mentioned above ) from the menu where shutdown restart are.
Ubuntu 13.10
and yes `sudo pm-hibernate` or `sudo hibernate` works
 
Any suggestions ? 
Thanks !

Comment: What do you get when you type `sudo pm-hibernate`?

Comment: It's possible you could write a cron job that checks to see if the battery has reached below a specific number, and then run `pm-hibernate` automatically.