# Laptop shuts down as soon as the battery is reached 65%

Tags: 14.04, shutdown, battery

I have Ubuntu 14.04 dual boot with Windows 8.1. Windows is working perfectly fine but in Ubuntu, Laptop battery discharges slowly than the rate at which it used to discharge previously, and my PC shuts down immediately as the battery is reached around 65-70%. There is no problem with charging as after Shutting down, it charges uniformly from 0% to 100%. How to fix this?

Comment: If under Ubuntu the battery indicator is at 75% and you reboot into Windows, what's the battery indicator there?

Comment: Does the computer just cut out or gracefully shutdown? It may be overheating.

Comment: No, it just cut out, as in the case of battery going to 0%.

Comment: This answer from AskUbuntu helped me:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/92794/how-to-change-critically-low-battery-value