# Samsung laptop running Ubuntu 15.04 shuts down at 30% battery without warning

Tags: power-management, 15.04, battery, samsung

My laptop shuts down suddenly at 30% battery when not charging. It does not show any warning. The screen turns black all of a sudden and I can only reboot after I've plugged in and started charging again.
I have a Samsung NP350V5X - S01IN. I'm running Ubuntu 15.04. What should I do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change critically low battery value?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/92794/how-to-change-critically-low-battery-value)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an end of life battery?

Check in the Bios (under boot options) if there is:

`Smart Battery Calibration` entry, then run it!

So restart and check the accuracy of the battery level, you can access it clicking the energy panel icon (the battery icon top right on the panel).

Comment: Thanks! I'm almost 3 years late in answering :P Yes, it was an old battery and I did exchange it. It's fine now.