# No " Low Battery " warning in Cinnamon Desktop

Tags: 14.04, unity, battery, cinnamon

I am using Cinnamon desktop over 14.04. The problem is, I do not get " low battery " warning while in Cinnamon. I also have Gnome Desktop which gives the warning without any problem. Some time back, Unity got automatically removed from my PC. Could that be causing the problem. The battery status is always shown as 100 % in Cinnamon. Help please..

Comment: although you use desktop but i think it's off topic anyway check this link may help you http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60778/how-can-i-get-an-alert-when-my-battery-is-about-to-die-in-linux-mint

Comment: How can I add a Cron job ? Would be great if you could give the exact script and help me set a cron job as well. Thanks.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job

Comment: honestly i don't face this problem before on linux mint cinnamon but i hope these links help you :)

Comment: Perhaps you will be interested in one of my previous answers. It relies on a script , which makes use of `notify-send`. `notify-send` notification are desktop independent , so consider giving it a go. Link is here . Let me know if you'd like any modifications to it : http://askubuntu.com/a/763396/295286

Answer (score 0):

Open a browser and go to github. Create and account by registering your email and desired password.

Type in terminal:

```
ls -al ~/.ssh
```

Check the directories to see whether you already have any public ssh keys

By default, the filenames of the public keys are one of the following:

```
id_dsa.pub
id_ecdsa.pub
id_ed25519.pub
id_rsa.pub
```

If you see an existing public and private key pair listed (for example id_rsa.pub and id_rsa) then type

```
ssh-agent bash
ssh-add /location/of/key.pub
```

Test whether you can login

```
ssh -v host.with.pubkey
```

If you don't see any existing public key added then type:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"
ssh-add /location/of/key.pub
ssh -v host.with.pubkey
```

Now open another terminal and go to

```
cd /root/.ssh
ls
```

You will see your public rsa key listed as id_rsa.pub Do

```
vim id_rsa.pub
```

Open a browser and login to your github account. Go to settings --> ssh and gpg --> add new ssh -->

In the title bar type the name of your computer. Copy the entire content from vim and paste in in ssh key. Click add.

go to Personal access token --> Generate new token --> check all the boxes --> generate --> copy the token to a text file

Go to first terminal

```
ssh-agent $(ssh-add /root/.ssh/id_rsa; git clone https://github.com/robin92/cinnamon-power-applet.git)
```

When asked for user name enter it

When asked for password enter the personal access token

```
cp -R power@airlog.pisz.pl/ ~/.local/share/cinnamon/applets/
```

Then add the applet to the desired panel

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you @rancho But when I type, it is asking for password  " Username for 'https://github.com':  "

Comment: Simply creaate an account in github, then again give the commands and enter your credentials

Comment: Ok. Will do and update :)

Comment: I am facing a strange issue. My password is working on browser, but not on terminal. Says " fatal authentication error ".

Comment: @user227495 I have updated the answer

Comment: Thanks for the continuous help. But I am still stuck at " remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/robin92/cinnamon-power-applet.git/' " after entering id and password for last command.

Comment: @user227495 updated my answer try this one

Comment: This is where I am stuck after making the key " Permissions 0644 for '/home/dpa/.ssh/id_rsa.pub' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
dpa@dpa-Vtro-35:~$ ssh -v id_rsa.pub
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
ssh: Could not resolve hostname id_rsa.pub: Name or service not known

Comment: give me the output of sudo find -name "id_rsa" and   sudo find -name "id_rsa.pub"

Comment: Stuck again at " find: paths must precede expression: and
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]  " . Thanks for helping :)

Comment: You have done something clearly wrong, it is --> root@lenovo#:/home/user# find -name "id_rsa" --> output --> root@lenovo#:/home/user# find -name "id_rsa.pub" --> output, such kind of error is not possible

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40926/discussion-between-user227495-and-rancho).