# May I change the notification of low battery?

Tags: battery, notification, settings

I always wonder that when receiving this notification.

I'd like to change the 10% value to 25%.

May I?

Thx in advance!!!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to monitor battery condition and pop-up notification?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/603285/how-to-monitor-battery-condition-and-pop-up-notification) and this [Additional reference](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762777/how-do-i-configure-the-low-battery-notifications)

Answer (score 1):

This is really easy to do with the help of `dconf-editor`. If you do not already have it on your system, you can install it like this:

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install dconf-editor
```

Once installed, you can access it like any desktop application.

[image: dconf-editor in the application list]

You can also open it from the terminal by typing: `dconf-editor`.

Once open, go to: `org` > `gnome` > `settings-daemon` > `plugins` > `power`. Scroll down a bit until you see "percentage-low" You will see something like this:

[image: plugins - power]

Click on that and you will see the current system settings for the low-battery message:

[image: percentage-low settings]

Toggle "Use Default Value" off and change 10 to 25 (or any other number you would like to see). Then click "Apply":

[image: Apply the new value]

That's all there is to it. No need to restart any services or reboot the machine. If you would like to change this back to the default value later, just return to `dconf-editor` and make the change.

Hope this gives you what you need.

Comment: what a fantastic explanation !! Thnk you so much !!