# Change critical battery level in ubuntu 20?

Tags: power-management, battery

Ubuntu 20:

I have change critical battery levels using the method in this post:
[How to change critically low battery value?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92794/how-to-change-critically-low-battery-value)

It worked that time. But next time again battery level reached to default 5% and then the notification came. I again changed but next time it again changes to 5 %.

Please help.
Thanks.