# Does upower's CriticalPowerAction=HybridSleep interfere with tlp's recalibrate?

Tags: 18.04, power-management, laptop, battery, tlp

The [tlp documentation](https://linrunner.de/tlp/usage/tlp.html) describes `tlp recalibrate` as follows:

> `sudo tlp recalibrate [ BAT0 | BAT1 ]`
> This command works as follows:
>
> - Resets the charge thresholds to factory defaults 96/100 %
> - Discharges the selected battery completely (see description of tlp discharge above)
> - When discharging is complete the command terminates; it does not wait for the charge to complete
> - **Important**: to complete the recalibration process, let the battery charge to 100 % subsequently (you may power off but not remove AC power)

I have `/etc/UPower/UPower.conf` set up to go into `HybridSleep` at a battery percentage of 3%.

If I want to recalibrate my battery, using `sudo tlp recalibrate BAT0`, do I have to temporarily disable upower by changing the upower config to as follows? Or does upower not interfere because the battery can still finish discharging while the laptop is in HybridSleep?

```
UsePercentageForPolicy=true
PercentageAction=0
```

---

(This is a follow-up question to the explanations given in [What kind of battery management is preinstalled on a clean Ubuntu 18.04 install?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1302853/606260))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sleep condition is never met, because the laptop is connected to AC while discharging the battery during recalibration.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any source for that? Otherwise I think I'll only be able to accept once I've tried it. (edit: oh wait, you *are* the source. But still, where could I have found that info?)

Comment: It's just reasoning. The condition makes sense when on battery power, it doesn't on AC power.

Comment: Fair enough. But many tools do things that don't make sense

Comment: Sense is not always obvious at first glance ... ;)