# How to get charging alert in Ubuntu?

Tags: battery

How to get a charging alert in Ubuntu?
I am using a laptop. At the time of using the laptop suddenly goes to shut down because ubuntu not giving the low battery alert.

So pls help me!

Comment: Ubuntu version please?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu by default gives warning messages when the battery is running low. That it doesn't strongly suggest that your battery is starting to fail. A degraded battery looses capacity, and may suddenly loose power, rather than gradually.

You may be helped temporarily by setting the warning levels higher. See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1302564/what-kind-of-battery-management-is-preinstalled-on-a-clean-ubuntu-18-04-install/1302853#1302853) to learn how this could be configured.

Adapting the thresholds may trigger warnings earlier, and allow you to be warned in time. Still, in practice, these warnings may, if they appear, appear very soon if your battery is already in a very bad shape. The only fundamental solution then will be to install a new battery pack. You will be good then for at least another three years.

Comment: While the power plugin partially remains relevant, I believe those specific gsettings settings are not taking effect any more. Instead, corresponding changes made in the `/etc/UPower/UPower.conf` file might be effective: https://askubuntu.com/a/1302853/1157519 Actually this would worth sorting out. (I unfortunately cannot take part in it, because I use my laptop without a battery now.)

Comment: Could it be relying on the value of `org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power priority`?

Comment: @Levente thank you for this information. I surely will also not test myself, so I took the easy way and referred to the question for specific information on how to change these thresholds. I shared the experience of a swollen battery with you, but on a Dell XPS, the computer won't work at all with the battery removed :-(