# Computer hibernates when unplugged from powersource

Tags: 11.10, hibernate

My MSI notebook shuts down everytime I unplug it from the power supply. Even when the battery is full, this is quite annoying.

Anyone seen this before or have a fix for it ?

Comment: It is default for computers with very low battery to hibernate, so data is not lost. Is your battery in good state?

Comment: @Wolter Hellmund: Trust me, his battery is in good state :) I also have this problem with an MSI notebook. Here's another one: http://askubuntu.com/questions/65889/computer-shuts-down-when-unplugged The only workaround I found is suspend-unplug-unsuspend. Then it doesn't shut down

Comment: Possibly related to http://askubuntu.com/questions/70877/battery-critically-low-at-85

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is flagged for closure. =)

Comment: Well, I think of it as a bug an answer might be nice for other people, but I fear it's up to ubuntu devs or MSI :(

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).